# Issues with Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end On internet explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer is showing the following classic error: 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampplite\htdocs\obg001\tpl\chooseStart.tpl.php on line 133`  which is most of times a missing bracer, however there are two things i do not understand completely:

1.- php_error_log is not reporting any error

2.- the error only appears on IE

i do not find any missing bracer myself. The code without almost anything else more than the brackets is:

```
    <?php
        if ($_SESSION['game']['status']=='OPEN'){
    ?> 
    <?php
                        foreach($gamers as $gamer){
            }
    ?>

    <?php
        }else{
    ?>
    <?php
            foreach($gamers as $gamer){
            }
        }
    ?>
    <?php 
        if($_SESSION['game']['status']=='CHOOSING'){         
    ?>
    <?php
        }
        else if ($_SESSION['game']['status']=='DONECHOOSING'){
    ?>
    <?php
        }
        else if ($_SESSION['game']['status']=='ROLLING'){
    ?>
    <?php 
            if ($canRoll['result']==true){
    ?>
    <?php        
            }else{
    ?>
                <?php  ?>    
    <?php
            }
    ?>    
    <?php
        }else if ($_SESSION['game']['status']=='DONEROLLING'){
            if($_SESSION['game']['userId'] == $_SESSION['user']['userId']){
    ?>
    <?php
            }
        }else {        
            if($_SESSION['game']['userId'] == $_SESSION['user']['userId']){        
    ?>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
```

If you want to see the code without the cutoff go [here](http://codepad.org/dHVgYtvf)

Thank you very much.

**Server configuration:**

- Operative Syste: windows 7 x64
- ApacheFriends XAMPP version 1.7.7:

  - Apache 2.2.21
  - MySQL 5.5.16 (Community Server)
  - PHP 5.3.8 (VC9 X86 32bit thread safe) + PEAR
- [php.ini](http://codepad.org/dSOputwe)

**Update**:

If i get it correctly my php.ini should log everything:

```
 error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
 display_errors = On 
 log_errors = On
 error_log =  "\xampplite\php\logs\php_error_log"
```

Also, the project was and is created and coded by myself only, so i'm sure there is not one directive to not log errors in any of the includes.

**Update 2**

If i add intentionally a closing bracer to the last line of that code i get in php_error_log the following line:

`[12-Jul-2012 22:23:30] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampplite\htdocs\obg001\tpl\chooseStart.tpl.php on line 139`

So PHP is login parsing errors after all, which should happen when IE loads the page and again it does not.

I can finally add that the page loads perfect even on a iPad so this just does not make much sense to me.

Comment: The error isn't in that file - it's likely in one of the many includes you have.

Comment: Yep, there is probably a typo in one of the included files.

Comment: @Deefour ok i will look in the other files, however should that error be present in php_error_log? The only error in there is a `[12-Jul-2012 22:02:27] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in C:\xampplite\htdocs\index.php on line 7` from facebook library.

Comment: Again, depends on your code in those includes. You could have `log_errors` off in your `php.ini` and enabled in that facebook library, or on in your `php.ini` and disabled in one of those includes.

Comment: try to clearing the cache of IE

Comment: @DavidBélanger it is used in the original file to prevent the multiple use of `echo` to write html code. I only left it on the above code because i'm not sure if that is part of the problem.

Comment: @Laxus wow, i neved expected to be a problem with the cache, darn thank you very much! Is there a way to prevent this type of errors from happening to clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem depends on IE, which keeps a cached version of the old page, without calling the application.

under development is recommended to send this header

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```